# How to resize an image inside of a materialize CSS slider to make it fit

Tags: css, image, materialize, image-resizing, autoresize

I'm using Materialize CSS slider but the images I'm using in the slider are not resizing to fit, only half of the image shows in the slider.
I tried multiple CSS rules to fix this but nothing is working. The issue is only with the height.

Here's the CSS I tried so far:

```
.first_image{
    height 100%;
    max-height:100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Here's the HTML code for it:

```
<section class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="./img/business1.jpg" alt="" class="first_image">
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I also added the code on [codepen here](https://codepen.io/randomxy/pen/ERVLRZ), please check it out.

Comment: you only using css or bootstrap?

Comment: I'm using css and materialize css framework. specifically the slider javascript component.

Comment: What is the issue? Your codepen works fine. Also any solutions that declare a new called img-responsive., ignore these - materialize already has an img-responsive class: https://materializecss.com/media-css.html

Answer (score 4):

You should set

```css
.img-responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Image" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, however that didn't work still. The entire image is not yet showing. I've updated my question here to include the code on codepen, please take a look if you can.

Comment: object-fit only works on images that have both with and height set to 100%, and is not recognised in IE. https://caniuse.com/#search=object%20fit

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Code**

```
.slider .slides .img-responsive{

  max-width: 100%;
  height: 900px;

}
```

**JS Code**

```
  //init slider
  $('.slider').slider({
    indicators: true,
    height: 900,
    transition: 500,
    interval: 6000
  });
```

Essentially the height on the img and slider should match. If it happens to be to big for your liking, you can resize the image itself straight from the source its coming from (i.e the img folder)

Comment: at first, glance seems like a wrong answer, please do more research, and no need to use JS, use CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Ok two things:

**#1 Materialize already has a responsive image class:**

```
// Images
img.responsive-img,
video.responsive-video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Lines 156-162 inside globals.scss.

https://materializecss.com/media-css.html

In any case, when I checked the codepen just now, the images were full width. I took off both the extra img-responsive declaration, and the class from the image itself, and it still works for me in chrome.

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/XWbmvbE

**#2 Materialize uses background images for it's slider**

the Materialize slider only uses the image tag to get the src of the image, which it then applies to the background of the img tag. So the img-responsive stuff is irrelevant here. Below is the actual code from the full screen slider demo:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="" style="opacity: 0.0568148; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464817739973-0128fe77aaa1?dpr=1&amp;auto=compress,format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1199&amp;h=799&amp;q=80&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;crop=&quot;);"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption center-align" style="opacity: 0.0568148; transform: translateY(-94.3185px);">
        <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="active" style="opacity: 0.943185; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1414849424631-8b18529a81ca?q=75&amp;fm=jpg&amp;s=0e993004a2f3704e8f2ad5469315ccb7&quot;);"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption left-align" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateX(-100px) translateY(0px);">
        <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="opacity: 0; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);" class="">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ununsplash.imgix.net/uploads/1413259835094dcdeb9d3/6e609595?q=75&amp;fm=jpg&amp;s=6a4fc66161293fc4a43a6ca6f073d1c5&quot;);"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption right-align" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateX(100px);">
        <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

If you dig into the css, you can see that it is already forcing the images to be full width:

```
.slider .slides li img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```